# Docker: calling an executable from php does not work

Tags: php, docker, laradock

I have set up a Laradock environment with Nginx and php-fpm containers running. From PHP I want to call an executable:

```
<?php
    print exec('whoami'); // www-data
    echo "<br>";
    exec('/usr/local/bin/assimp version', $output, $returnValue);
    print $returnValue;   // 127
    echo "<br>";
    print_r($output);      // Array ( ) 
?>
```

The return value 127 sounds to me as if the file is not found...

But when I enter the container with the user "www-data" everything works fine:

```
docker-compose exec --user www-data php-fpm bash
assimp version // -> valid info response
```

As I was unsure if the executable has to be placed in "workspace" or in the php-fpm container I tried both with the same result. Also putting the executable in the /var/www directory did not help.

The executable was added by the Dockerfile:

```
USER www-data
COPY ./assimp /usr/local/bin/assimp
COPY ./libassimp.so.4.1.0 /usr/local/lib/libassimp.so.4.1.0
RUN ln -s /usr/local/lib/libassimp.so.4.1.0 /usr/local/lib/libassimp.so
RUN chmod 777 /usr/local/bin/assimp
RUN echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
RUN echo 'export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Any ideas how to fix this issue or how to continue with the debugging? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Many typical `docker run` paths don’t actually read `.bashrc`, and putting things there in a Dockerfile isn’t a great practice.  Just put things in directories that are already in the search/loader paths.

Comment: Thanks for you comment. I moved the executable to `/usr/bin` and the lib to `/usr/lib`. The result is still the same. I found out that even if the lib is in a standard folder it is not found:
`ldconfig -p | grep libassimp.so` in the php-fpm container delivers no result.
Doing this in the workspace container works and the lib is found. Is it possible to tell php to execute a file from the workspace container and not from the php-fpm container?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Return code 127 is for a file not found, but not necessarily the one your are executing.
Here you setup some libs, but when the docker container is executed, your `bashrc` is not read, thus, the dynamic loader (`/lib/ld-linux[...].so`) doesn't find your `libassimp.so.4.1.0` thus, the process returns 127.

You should set your `PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` with Dockerfile's `ENV` directives like this:

`ENV PATH="/usr/local/bin:${PATH}"
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib`

Comment: @reply Thanks for your hint. I tried what you suggested but still get the same error. What I did:

`docker-compose stop workspace php-fpm`

Added these lines to the .env file:

    ENV PATH="/usr/local/bin:${PATH}"
    ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib

`docker-compose up -d workspace php-fpm`

The issue is still the same, my php file returns 127.

Comment: I can confirm now that it is an issue with the library path. When I build the executable without the need for an external library, everything works fine. So this is a usable workaround for me.